# How to avoid apt-get -y dist-upgrade being interactive with waagent?

Tags: 12.04, apt, upgrade, unattended-upgrades, azure

I have an Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS created in Azure Cloud. I create it from a Jenkins powershell build that:
 1. Create VM in Azure
 2. Execute some remote SSH commands (among them apt-get dist-upgrade)
 3. Create a Virtual Image from VM

But the build hangs in Step 2.In step 2, among other commands, I execute:

```
apt-get update
apt-get -q -y dist-upgrade
```

The intention of -y is to avoid interactive questions. If I run manually from a shell **apt-get -q -y dist-upgrade** it works fine until twice it gets stuck:

**First interactive question**:
[image]

**Second interactive question**:
[image]

Parameter -y is supposed to avoid this situation. As you can see the offending package is [waagent](https://github.com/Azure/WALinuxAgent), that is Microsoft Azure Linux Agent and it comes installed by default when I finish step 1

My question is: **How can I avoid these interactive questions?** (either answering Yes, or No, or avoiding to upgrade this package or something else)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems that clashes with config files are pretty common in apt-get (dkpg)
I solve the problem by using:

```
apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" dist-upgrade
```

The options mean:

- **--force-confdef**: Ask dpkg to decide alone when it can and prompt otherwise...
- **--force-confold**: Do not modify the current configuration file...

Comment: Wish downvoters would state what's wrong; works for me!

Answer (score 0):

May be you can also try:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get dist-upgrade -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" --force-yes
```